# Adding session variable into MYSQL query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session-variables

Im trying to pass two variables into a mysql query, and its getting stuck when passing the session variable in below:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM Clients 
                      WHERE Username = '$new_username' 
                      AND Username != '$_SESSION['Username']'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `"SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE Username = '$new_username' AND Username != '".$_SESSION['Username']."'"`

Comment: "Getting stuck" isn't really an error message. What output is this generating?

Comment: Cheers Shakti thats worked :)

Comment: **I hope you see now that your question has nothing to do with sessions nor with mysql,** but just **PHP strings syntax issue**

Comment: Also note Salman's answer. SQL injections is a thing to avoid...

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because your single quotes `'$_SESSION['Username']'` have been ended by the value in the session. Changing this to `'" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

This will work but this is **VERY, VERY BAD**:

```
$check = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM  Clients 
    WHERE Username = '$new_username' 
    AND   Username != '{$_SESSION['Username']}'
") or die(mysql_error());
```

This too shall work and recommended way of doing it:

```
$check = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM  Clients 
    WHERE Username  = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($new_username) . "' 
    AND   Username <> '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Username']) . "'
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why no one say about "text text $array[key] text" syntax?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Clients 
WHERE Username = '$new_username' 
AND   Username != '$_SESSION[Username]'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you embed arrays in to strings, you have to seperate them by concatenating them or using curly braces.

```
$string = "text text {$array['key']} text";
```

or

```
$string = "text text " . $array['key'] . " text";
```